# How can i set default param in ngResource to be POST

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angularjs-factory

I have a simple AJAX request that needs a csrf token for every call and i define it like so:

```
app.factory('auth', ['$resource', '$cookies', function($resource, $cookies){

    var getCsrf = function() {
        //get csrf token from cookie
    };

    return {
        login: $resource('auth/login', {}, {
                'q' : {
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {csrf_token: getCsrf()}
                }
            }),
        // ... some more requests
    };
}]);
```

As i understood it you can specify the default `url` parameters as second param of the `$resource()`-call, in my case the empty object `{}`. Apparently the data i set in the configurations object under `params: ...` also gets send via GET and not with the specified POST-method.

One way would be to manually put the csrf_token in where i make the call to the api-function, but i'd like to keep it clean. Is there a way to tell angular what method to use for the default params? So i could simply use ..

```
auth.login.q(email, password, ...).then( ... );
```

.. without having to implement the csrf-getter function into all my calls. Also i am relatively new to AngularJS so a simple answer would be great!

Comment: You could just make a resource wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy way to this in angular:
set the xsrf cookie name and header name defaults in the config module.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    // response cookie name
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrf_cookie';
    // request header name where the value of the cookie get set
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'HTTP_X_XSRF_TOKEN';

    // to set ajax request header
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = { 'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'};
}
```